# How to get data from ajax call when application is like 3 tier in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have two service one for only get the ajax call and the second service is to manipulate the data that is got from the service now i want to return this data to the controller but the data is not getting updated below is my code

```html
 angular.module("Data", []).service("DataService", function ($http) {

     
        return {
            Data:  
               function (url, callback) {
                    $http.get(url).success(callback);     

            },
        }
    })

    angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).service("HomeService", function (DataService) {
      
        return 
        {  
            Dataw3:    
                DataService.Data('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php', function (results) {
                    return results.records
                });
            
     
        }
          

    })






    angular.module("Home").controller("HomeCntrl", function ($scope, HomeService) {
                 
            console.log(DataService.Dataw3)  
   
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using the `factory` syntax with a `service` declaration.

```
angular.module("Data", []).factory("DataService", function ($http) {

angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).factory("HomeService", function (DataService) {
```

should probably do the trick.

Then, you are trying to return a value, from a callback, which simply does not work. Dataw3 should be a function which take a callback as an argument, in which you put your console.log :

```
angular.module("Data", []).factory("DataService", function ($http) {   
    return {
        Data:  
           function (url, callback) {
                $http.get(url).success(callback);     
           }
    };
});

angular.module("Home", ["Data"]).factory("HomeService", function (DataService) {
    return {
        Dataw3:
            function(callback){
                DataService.Data('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php', function (results) {
                    callback(results);
                });
            }
    };
});

angular.module("Home").controller("HomeCntrl", function ($scope, HomeService) {          
    HomeService.Dataw3(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I recommand you dig further into service vs factory in angular, and asynchronous calls in javascript, so you can have a better understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: it show an error as expected identifier in function dataW3

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work now, just a problem with the return statement.

Comment: get the below error    ReferenceError: DataService is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (HtmlPage2.html:43)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)
    at jqNodes.$get.extend.instance (angular.js:8516)
    at angular.js:7762
    at forEach (angular.js:334)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7761)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7140)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7019)
    at angular.js:1460
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14570)